# A weird multiplication

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

Let's see who can find the result of the last equation:

$$\begin{align}30\times43&=1111\\23\times60&=2345\\35\times42&=9876\\39\times40&=\text{????}\end{align}$$

Comment: @TheSimpliFire should see this if he/she has not already :D

Answer (score 22, accepted):

39*40 =

> 0000

because

> 1290, 1380, 1470 and 1560 are the real results of those operations

and that way,

> each column are those results